# Che rapporto di intercambialità c'è tra bene/tanto e meglio/di più?

Tags: grammar

So che in alcune costruzioni frasali sono intercambiabili, come ad esempio qui:

"Conosco di più/meglio la prima parte che la seconda"

"Capisco tanto/bene quello che c'è scritto"

Mi viene in mente il verbo "ricordare" nel uso suo transitivo e andando ad orecchio  mi verrebbe  da dire:

"me lo ricordo bene quel dettaglio"  ma non  "me lo ricordo tanto quel dettaglio".

Ora, sono sicuro che ci sia qualche regola per capire in quali casi siano intercambiabili e in quali no.
Potreste darmi una dritta e chiarirmi la situazione?

Answer (score 1):

“Tanto” e “bene” raramente sono intercambiabili.

**Tanto** si riferisce a una *quantità*, e richiede un termine di paragone, eventualmente implicito (per esempio “Non ho mangiato tanto (quanto penseresti, quanto l'ultima volta etc.)”). **Bene** invece esprime una *qualità*. Lavorare o studiare tanto, per esempio, è molto diverso da farlo bene.

Lo stesso vale per “di più” (quantità) e “meglio” (qualità).

Ci saranno forse azioni o situazioni in cui qualità e quantità coincidono, ma non è la norma.

Per quanto riguarda nello specifico gli esempi, conoscere una cosa *più* di un'altra è simile a conoscerla *meglio*, ma dà comunque l'idea che, per esempio, hai solo assimilato più dettagli. Quanto al secondo esempio, “Capisco tanto quello che c'è scritto” non suona molto idiomatico. Tendenzialmente, una cosa si può capire bene, a fondo, del tutto, completamente etc. Semmai, sembra che manchi qualcosa; per esempio, “Capisco tanto quello che c'è scritto che non ho bisogno di ripassarlo ulteriormente”.

Comment: la seconda frase è scorretta o solo poco idiomatica? Ci sta usare indifferentemente tanto o bene in quella frase

Comment: Sicuramente non è indifferente usare “tanto” o “bene”, per quello che dicevo sopra (quantità/qualità). In secondo luogo, se leggessi o sentissi “Capisco tanto quello che c'è scritto” mi suonerebbe un po' strana.

Comment: Grazie. Hai detto che in rari casi sono intercambiabili. Sapresti darmi, per favore,  una piccola spiegazione di come sia possibile questa intercambialità e in quali tipi di casi si presenti?  Magari lo potreati aggiungere alla tua risposta principale  o anche qui sotto.

Comment: @Nakamura. Lo farei volentieri, se fossi in grado. Qui non si tratta più di lingua italiana, ma di filosofia. Ci sono situazioni nella vita umana in cui quantità e qualità sono intercambiabili? Il cibo per un affamato? I risultati di una gara d'atletica? La tua opinione vale la mia.